# Resetting a integer counter vb.net

Tags: vb.net, integer, counter

If I have a double variable that goes through a loop and gets numbers added to it, is it just as simple as saying variablename = 0 to reset it?

Jonesy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that will definitely reset the value. You need to think carefully about whether you actually want a double or an integer though - your title says one, and your text says another. In particular, you should almost never treat double values for equality, whereas with integers that's fine. So you wouldn't want

```
If doubleValue = 10.1 Then
```

as your condition, but

```
If integerValue = 10
```

would be fine.

Comment: ok thanks, will changing it to variablename = 0.00 be better? It needs to be of type double

Comment: Not needed, @Jonesy. 0 is enough.